# Why the output is only half the link

Tags: php

I have a class that handles the pagination mechanism. I have these two functions that are givin' me a very hard time because I can't explain why the output is formatted wrong. My functions are:

```
    private function show_links() {
        echo '<div id="news_nav">';
        echo $this->show_prev_link();
        echo $this->show_next_link();       
        echo '</div>';
}   

    private function show_prev_link() {
        if (($this->start + 1) * self::$MAX_POSTS <= $this->total_posts) 
        {
            return '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 
                            '/inc/sandbox.php?s=' . $this->start+1 . 
                            '" target="_self">&laquo; Previous</a>'; 
        }

private function show_next_link() {
        if (($this->start - 1) * self::$MAX_POSTS >= 0)
        {
            return '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 
                           '/inc/sandbox.php?s=' . $this->start-1 . 
                           '" target="_self">Next &raquo;</a>'; 
        }
    }
```

And the output is:

```
1" target="_self">« Previous
```

I really don't understand why it is truncated like that and what is causing this, hope you can help sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap them in brackets, like so:

```
($this->start-1)
```

That you will have something like this:

```
return '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 
                        '/inc/sandbox.php?s=' . ($this->start+1) . 
                        '" target="_self">&laquo; Previous</a>';
```

Comment: OMG it was that stupid, thank you, I was goin' out of my mind trying to debug this!!